# how to plot spectrogram from IQ signal in matlab?

Tags: matlab, frequency, spectrogram, iq

I have an IQ signal saved using BladeRF platform in .bin file. I want to plot the spectrogram image of this signal in matlab

I tried with the existing function of matlab spectrogram but I got an image which is not expected, in fact my signal is over 2.4GHz but I don't get any thing in the spectrogram

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: it seems there's an experimental toolbox to precisely communicate with BladeRF boards here : https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/74591-communications-toolbox-support-package-for-bladerf-2-0?s_tid=srchtitle_bladeRF_2

Comment: have you tried this toolbox?